# Arduino JSON package - formatting sensor value

Tags: json, arduino, twilio

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SimpleDHT.h>

String input = "{\"temperature\":\"26\"};
SimpleDHT11 dht11;
byte temperature = 0;
int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;

void loop {

   StaticJsonBuffer<512> dataBuffer;

   if (err = dht11.read(2, &temperature, NULL)) == simpleDHTErrSuccess) {
       Serial.print((int) temperature);
       JsonObject& dataRoot = dataBuffer.parseObject(input);

       *long Temperature = dataRoot[String("temperature")];
       *Temperature = (long)temperature;
       *dataRoot[String("temperature")] = Temperature;

       String output;
       dataRoot.printTo(output);
}
```

I have here a snippet of Arduino code used to format a DHT11 temperature sensor readings in JSON, to allow for live streaming of the data on a web client. This was obtained from this project I am using for inspiration https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/watch-iot-sensors-esp32-javascript-nodejs-twilio-sync.html.

I am instead attempting to pull data from a Myoware muscle sensor. The amplitude value I am wanting can simply be queried like so:

```
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
```

I need help in understanding how the parseObject function works and what the purpose of the 'input' string is. All I want is for my sensor's value to be fed to the client side which displays it in a graph. The three lines I have asterisked are particularly confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `parseObject()` allocates and populate a JsonObject (that you can work with) from a JSON string.

The *"JsonObject"* in your code example is named `dataRoot` and is defined with

`JsonObject& dataRoot = dataBuffer.parseObject(input);`

where **`dataBuffer`** comes from `StaticJsonBuffer<512> dataBuffer;` which is the entry point for using the `ArduinoJson` library, and

where **`input`** has the value of the JSON string `"{\"temperature\":\"26\"}"` which follows the standard JSON attribute-value pair format (you need a JSON string to work with and then send it to the client side).

After `JsonObject& dataRoot = dataBuffer.parseObject(input);` is executed, you get `dataRoot` as an object with a property named `temperature` and you can access this property with `dataRoot[String("temperature")]`

So the three lines:

```
   long Temperature = dataRoot[String("temperature")];
   Temperature = (long)temperature;
   dataRoot[String("temperature")] = Temperature;
```

are used to update the value of the `temperature` attribute with whatever is read from the sensor.

A bit confusing in the example code is the fact that the name of the JSON attribute is `temperature` and also the name for the variable to hold the temperature read from sensor is also `temperature`. They are different things.

Comment: Thank you truly for your thoughtful, comprehensive answer!